# Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined error in strange situations

Tags: javascript, google-maps

google map javascript API showing `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined`
 in some strange situations like removing an input element from the page. The error is gone when reversing the changes

Comment: Plunker/Fiddler link please

Comment: @VipinKumar https://jsfiddle.net/rahulreghunath/x5kzcqLa/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your JS code in `$(document).ready(function(){ })`

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // Place your JS code here
  });
<script/>
```

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: works after putting jQuery event handler function inside the ready function